# Is there any option with 'ls' command that I see only the directories?

Tags: ls, utilities

Sometimes, I need to check only the directories not files. Is there any option with the command ls? Or is there any utility for doing that?

**EDIT**: I'm using Mac OS X, and `ls -d` gives me `.` even though I have directories.

Comment: Can somebody explain why `ls -d` gives only `.` and why the `*/` must be added to the end to make it work?

Comment: @cwd If you don't specify any files, `ls` defaults to `.`.  And `-d` means don't print the directory's contents, print the directory itself.

Comment: @cwd try using `ls -p` it shows the `/` after the directory names. So `*/` is just a pattern which is matched against the directory name and `/` combo.

Comment: I created a function implementing @Steven_D's answer for my ~/.bash_aliases file: https://gist.github.com/rjurney/998f4951a57bfa5daeb9a6c18f6f4827

Answer (score 146, accepted):

I know there is already a selected answer, but you can get the requested behavior with just `ls`:

```
ls -ld -- */
```

(Note that the '--' marks the end of parameters, preventing folder names beginning with a hyphen from being interpreted as further command options.)

This will list all the non-hidden (unless you configure your shell's globs to expand them) directories in the current working directory where it is run (note that it also includes symbolic links to directories).  To get all the subdirectories of some other folder, just try:

```
ls -ld /path/to/directory/*/
```

Note that the -l is optional.

Comment: Nice.  I never considered that directories have an implicit `/` on the end--but now that I see you answer it makes sense.  After all, tab-completion always adds it.

Comment: `-d for dir, -l for long format`. whats the purpose of `--` ?

Comment: While this looks short and works for most cases, one may not want to use this approach when a true directory is needed, not a directory's symlink.  So `find` is actually a good choice in that case.

Comment: `find` also has the advantage when the number of directories exceeds the maximum argument length.

Comment: Working backwards, I just realised you can simply ignore anything with an extension: `ls -alhF --ignore=*.*`. Not sure how well this would handle 'hidden' folders, i.e. `.myHiddenFolder`

Comment: I created a function to do this called by the command `lsd`: https://gist.github.com/rjurney/998f4951a57bfa5daeb9a6c18f6f4827

Comment: Just a note on @Timmah s comment:  Directories may also contain dots in their name.

Comment: This does not list *only* directories as requested

Answer (score 26):

No, but a simple `find` command will do it (here using the `-{min,max}depth` GNU extensions, also found on most implementations theses days):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

Or the POSIX (standard) equivalent:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type d
```

On FreeBSD and some of its derivatives (including [macOS](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/find/)), you can also do:

```
find . -depth 1 -prune -type d
```

Those also include hidden directories (not the `.` or `..` special directories) and don't sort the list of files. It also adds a `./` prefix to each file which with the GNU implementation of `find`, you can remove by adding `-printf '%P\n'`.

or `grep` (assuming file names don't contain newline characters):

```
ls -p | grep /
```

(add the `-A` option to `ls` to include hidden ones).

You could then alias either one if necessary.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 it was `-maxdepth 1`. Also `find` wanted me to flip the order: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d`

Comment: That `ls -F | grep /` solution works wonders!  It seems to be the only one I can get to work on my FreeBSD machine.  I think using Fish means that anything with `*/` may not work?

Comment: I've never worked with Fish so I'm not sure about that  but the -F option can work wonders.

Comment: This gives me errors on Linux Mint with find version 4.4.2. I get `find: warning: you have specified the -depth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-depth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.` (If I use `maxdepth` instead I still get the warning, but it's followed by the correct output.)

Comment: @EricLeschinski, the functional equivalent of FreeBSD's `-depth 1` with GNU `find`'s `-{min,max}depth` would be `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`. FreeBSD's `-depth 1` yields true for files at depth 1, but doesn't otherwise stop find from descending into subdirectories, so `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` (which is now also supported by all BSDs including FreeBSD) is better, though you could also do `find . -depth 1 -prune -type d` to get something equivalent.

Answer (score 9):

I also needed to view hidden directories so have modified the suggestion above to fit my needs

```
ls -d -- */ .*/
```

(depending on the shell, that may also include `.` and `..`)

Comment: Then there's `ls -a` to include directory entries whose names begin with a dot (.), which avoids the annoyance of matching `.` and `..`.

Answer (score 8):

I like the [tree](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) utility to get an overview over the directory structure. It's available in MacPorts and all Linux distributions I've tried.

```
tree -d -L 2
```

That would show all directories, two levels deep.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh` (as found by default on macOS, it even used to be `/bin/sh` there, and it's the default login shell in newer versions), you'd use glob qualifiers to select files based on their type:

- List non-hidden directories:

  ```
  ls -ld -- *(/)
  ```
- List all directories:

  ```
  ls -ld -- *(D/)
  ```

  (`.` and `..` are always excluded, add them individually if you want them)
- Also include symlinks to directories:

  ```
  ls -ld -- *(D-/)
  ```

  (`-` makes so further qualifiers apply after symlink resolution).

Here, using `-l` to get a long listing. For printing the list of matching files, you don't need `ls`, you can replace `ls -ld` with `print -rC1` (`print` `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn, `print` being builtin). You may also want to add the `N` glob qualifier so as to print nothing if there's no matching file instead of reporting an error:

```
print -rC1 -- *(ND/)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not just **one option** to list directories...

But you can use `-d` (list directories themselves, not their contents) and `*/` to match directories themselves:

`ls -d */`

And try to use the dot, for hidden ones, `ls -d .*/`.

Just for fun, try: `ls -d` and `ls */`. The differences will be clear!

Ref:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14352330/12453339
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447829/385133

Comment: Note that the accepted answer basically shows this already, together with `--` to protect against interpreting directory names starting with a dash as options.

Comment: This is a good link. There the tag "bash" is set. I only found "If followed by  a  /...." in man bash. in "Pathname Expansion", explaining "*".

Comment: Kusalananda, pls, read the first line from Steven D answer...
Mine is just shorter. And I clarify the option and the match.
Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Now the second (SE) link lacks the "bash" tag, and patrick's answer elegantly avoids explanations. If you compare with the `zsh` solution just above, you see it is a shell thing about _extended_ pattern matching. Where is that `*/` notation in bash defined?

Comment: What I meant in my previous comment was that the accepted answer will not start to behave strangely when there is a file or directory called, e.g., `-l` in the current directory.

Comment: Yes rastafile, https://stackoverflow.com/a/31603260/12453339 is a good explanation, really undervoted...

Answer (score 0):

Use ls command like this

```
❯ ls -1d plugins/*/
plugins/localizable/
plugins/redmine_agile/
plugins/redmine_gitlab_hook/
plugins/redmine_mermaid_macro/
plugins/redmine_open_links_in_new_window/
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ ls -p | grep /
```

The `-p` flag will make `ls` add a slash (`/') after each filename if that file is a directory.

Answer (score -2):

I think ls has a bug on Mac OS X. A workaround is to use grep... `ls -l / | grep "^d"`

Comment: It's nice to know I'm not the only person that uses the `grep "^d"` hack

Comment: As far as I know, the behavior he describes is not a bug and is the same if one is using GNU ls.  The -d option displays the listing for the directory and not the contents.  To see why this can be useful see the difference between: `ls -l /home` and `ls -dl /home`

Comment: Carats aren't special to the shell.  You can just use `ls -l / | grep ^d`.  If you *are* going to use quotes, since you don't need parameter expansion, make them *single* quotes.  `ls -l / | grep '^d'`.  Yes, I'm a pedant.  But really, do this.  :)

Answer (score -3):

```
ls -G
```

this will show your directories in blue

Comment: Do you see _only the directories_ when using this command ?

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way is to type the following command. This works across most UNIX and Linux platforms and versions. You can skip the `-F` if you want, but it is the argument that adds the / to the end of the directory name. The `-C` argument captures only directory names - all of them in the current directory. If you want to see only directories and subdirectories in the current path, simply add the `-R` argument (`ls -CFR`).

```
# ls -CF
/dir1  /dir2  /dir3  /beaches  /Work  /Other
```

Comment: In all `ls` implementations I know and in the POSIX specification of `ls`, `-C` is to output in _columns_, not to skip non-directory files. In your example, the `/` are printed before the file names, which no `ls` implementation would do. With `-F`, `/` is appended to the file name for directory files.

Comment: When I saw this answer, I wondered “Where is this true?” @StéphaneChazelas and Jeff Schaller — don’t you downvote blatantly wrong answers?

Comment: This doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04. standard terminal