# How can I list only the directories present in a directory using ls?

Tags: linux, directory, ls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any option with 'ls' command that I see only the directories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/is-there-any-option-with-ls-command-that-i-see-only-the-directories)

I have a directory with a lot of files but only a few directories.

To get a list of only the directories, what I do is this

```
ls -l | grep "^d"
```

I know I can alias it to make it faster, but is there some easier way of doing this that I do not know about?

I checked [`man ls`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls), but did not find any such flag there.

Also, `ls -d` displays only a `.`, nothing else.