# List symlinks in current directory?

Tags: find, ls, symlink

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/is-there-any-option-with-ls-command-that-i-see-only-the-directories) talks about finding directories in a current diretory. The solution is basically:

```
ls -d */
```

That's great but how can I easily list symlinks? Do I have to use something like

```
find . -xtype l -d 1
(intended to find symlinks max depth 1 - doesn't work)
```

Or is there an easier way? Can ls be used for this?

Comment: On my Ubuntu system, a quick look at its `man find` shows that `-d` is a synonym for `-depth` (for compatibility with FreeBSD, NetBSD, MacOS X and OpenBSD.), ie. it is not the same as `-maxdepth` . . . `-depth` *Process  each  directory's contents before the directory itself*

Answer (score 9):

In zsh (add `N` inside the parentheses to include symlinks whose name begins with a `.`):

```
echo *(@)
```

With most `find` implementations:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type l
```

POSIX-compliant:

```
find . -type d \! -name . -prune -o -type l -print
```

Or with a shell loop:

```
for x in * .*; do
  if [ -h "$x" ]; then echo "$x"; done
done
```

Comment: For the `-prune` option, you need to use `find topdir ! -name topdir -prune`; otherwise the starting directory is ignored as well.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't on a Mac, but

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type l
```

works for me.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `-type` and not `-xtype`:

```
   -xtype c
          The same as -type unless the file is a symbolic link.  For  sym‐
          bolic  links:  if the -H or -P option was specified, true if the
          file is a link to a file of type c; if the -L  option  has  been
          given,  true  if  c is `l'.  In other words, for symbolic links,
          -xtype checks the type of the file that -type does not check.
```

The default is `-P`, so the -xtype option will try to determine the resultant file, not the symlink itself.  Actually, I get some positive results, which seems like a bug. The `-P -xtype l` should return true (on a symlink) iff the resultant is itself a symbolic link.

Can also use: `ls -FA | sed -ne 's/@//p'` which will display only the symlinks.

Comment: nice ls solution

Comment: `sed -ne 's/@//p'` (and even `sed -ne 's/@$//p'`) is not a secure test, as the first version will give a false positive when `@` occurs anywhere in the *ls* output, and the second will return a false postive when a filename actually ends in `@`

Answer (score 1):

To find out only the files that are symlinks inside the current directory:

```
find . -type l -printf '%p -> %l\n'
```

This will recursively list all the symlink files.  Also, it shows the actual files it points to.