# Shell script to test ls output for directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, directory, test

I am trying to make a BASH script to test the files in the working directory and return the files that are directory files.

One approach that I can think of is, starting with ls and feeding the output into test -d.

I'm not sure what sort of looping would be best for testing each variable. And, how I can design the loop so that it can handle an unlimited amount of input from ls, not just designed for a maximum of say 20 variables.

Comment: Possibly related: [Is there any option with 'ls' command that I see only the directories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/is-there-any-option-with-ls-command-that-i-see-only-the-directories)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Don't parse the output of ls.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Instead, use `find(1)`:

```
find . -type d
```